Can't update Déjà hub. Snap release is deprecated and might not receive updates
Thats what I tried after anything else:
snap refresh --list
sudo apt-get install deja-dup
"I had to end the process (either through kill  or using the system monitor app), and I was then able to run sudo snap refresh snap-store."
snap-store --quit-on-close-for-update

Tried everything with flatpak here on this site
https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/D%C3%A9j%C3%A0_Dup/
See screenshots.
Thanks for helping. Kerstin
enter image description here
enter image description here




On the official web site is mentioned other command: flatpak install flathub org.gnome.DejaDup

Fehler: Remote "flathub" not found
